# Groupby pandas but perform calculation on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

| name | date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-03-01 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 2021-03-02 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2021-03-03 | 3 | 1 |
| A | 2021-03-04 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2021-03-05 | 3 | 1 |
| A | 2021-03-06 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2021-03-01 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2021-03-02 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 2021-03-03 | 3 | 1 |
| B | 2021-03-04 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 2021-03-05 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2021-03-06 | 0 | 0 |

I'd like to group by the names and find the number of days spanned by the nonzero entries of the other non-date columns (basically excluding any leading or trailing zeroes) to get something like:

| name | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 5 |
| B | 3 | 2 |

How can I do this without resorting to a for loop?

Comment: In the output, how is `col2` for `name` A 5 and not 3?

Comment: Basically, I want to count the number of days since the first nonzero entry until the last nonzero entry.

Comment: @mdrishan Are the dates continuos? Basically, are there any "gaps" in dates?

Comment: There are no gaps in the dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, [`np.trim_zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html) is what you are looking for:

```py
>>> import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name': ['A']*6 + ['B']*6, 'col1': [0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0], 'col2': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

>>> df
   name  col1  col2
0     A     0     1
1     A     0     0
2     A     3     1
3     A     1     0
4     A     3     1
5     A     1     0
6     B     1     0
7     B     2     0
8     B     3     1
9     B     0     1
10    B     0     0
11    B     0     0

>>> df.groupby('name').aggregate(lambda x: len(np.trim_zeros(x))).reset_index()
  name  col1  col2
0    A     4     5
1    B     3     2
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
def fn(x):
    i = x[(x != 0)].index
    return i[-1] - i[0] + 1 if len(i) > 0 else 0


print(df.groupby("name").agg({"col1": fn, "col2": fn}))
```

Prints:

```
      col1  col2
name            
A        4     5
B        3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that might scale a lot better for many groups [it avoids the `apply(lambda x:)` in favor of multiple groubpy builtin operations.]

Check for values !=0 then take a `cummax` within group in both directions to label the spans with True. Then `groupby` + `sum` to get the size.

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df1 = df[cols].ne(0)

df1 = df1.groupby(df['name']).cummax() & df1[::-1].groupby(df['name']).cummax()
df1 = df1.groupby(df['name']).sum()
```

---

```
print(df1)

      col1  col2
name            
A        4     5
B        3     2
```